# Cordova file not recognised when app built from command line + iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcodebuild

I have created an app in IOS with cordovav 2.1.0 framework. I am building the app from command line (from the path where the proj_name.xcodeproj exists) with command as :-

`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos6.1 -target blahapp`. I get the error as

```
fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found.
```

Why is this error coming? This error doesn't come when I run the app from xcode. Seems that it is not recognising the cordova files.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use latest [Phonegap version](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and CLI, that may solve your problem.
check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/X_S13Y_j79o) also